# I want to make a code that the user must input integer but if the user input string it will show the "Enter Integer: "

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, data-structures

Here my code but it doesn't work. I want to make if the user input string it shows "Enter Integer" but it shows error. Anyone can help me? Thanks[image: Here the error output]
int choice;

```
cout << "Please enter desired number: " ;

cin  >> choice;

while (!cin)
{
    if (!cin )
    {
        cout << "ENTER INTEGER: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize> :: max(), 'n');
        cin >> choice;
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
  cout<<"enter a number";
  int number;
  while(!(cin>>number)){
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout<<"enter an number\n";
  }
  cout<<number<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: This code will help you exiting loop without using break statement.